# What is the name of the code in programming language?

Tags: php, arrays, laravel

I am learning basic PHP . now I am learning laravel . but laravel array looking different.

`'paths' => [resource_path('views')]`

My question is what is name of = 'paths',

What is name of = 'resource_path',

What is name of = 'views' in programming language

Comment: I am not sure I understand what you're asking... - can you please try to elaborate?

Comment: In PHP, you can define arrays as: `array('foo', 'bar')` or as `['foo', 'bar']` no matter the framework. It's still PHP. However, I have _no idea_ what the actual question here is...

Comment: thank u so much in your ans. in my view i know 'paths' is a array name and 'resource_path('views'),' is a element. but what is the 'resource_path' ? and what is the 'views'? What could it be? 'resource_path' is the function? and 'views' is a argument?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In PHP, inside the lines

```
$array = [
  'paths' => [resource_path('views'),]
];
```

- `'paths'` is an *index* of the array
- `resource_path` is a *function*
- `'views'` is a string passed as a *parameter* to the function `resource_path`

As a suggestion, you should advance a little more in PHP before using laravel.